# Android mysterious margin in some listview item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm writing a common listview with some custom views. Nothing is so special about it.

But when I run this in my galaxy s7, a mysterious horizontal spacing is created in the center of the custom item view.

Here is an abstract version of the custom item view which will be returned on the getView() of the listView baseAdapter.

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_dutch, this, true);

    }
}
```

adding code such as setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(..., ...)); has no effect.

The layout is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUnRead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text=""

            android:textColor="@color/colorUnread"
            android:textSize="9dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="PM 3:11"
            android:textColor="@color/color_chatcrey"
            android:textSize="9dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:background="@drawable/img_chat_bubble_white_you_02_android"
            android:id="@+id/llBubble"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/..."
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/..." />

            <!-- RED BOX -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TOTAL"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTotalPoint"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/..." />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- PURPLE BOX -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonSnsShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/..." />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It results like this;
[image]

On the above screenshot, there should be no spacing between the red box and the purple button. Actually, on the android studio ui editor, I do not see any spacing, but it just shows up in runtime.

But in another project which I made to test this, it appears just fine like the image below.

[image]

There seems to be no difference in logic on showing custom views as listView items between the two projects. Why should this happen?

Comment: I've seen a number of those issues specifically with samsung devices over the years. Try to set the app theme explicitly if you don't already. Samsung device defaults are often a bit haphazardly implemented.

Comment: I assume you have exactly one view type in the `ListView`. Can you please indicate in your layout file which part belongs to the RED and PURPLE?

Comment: No, actually, I have more than five view types inside my view. The above code is a shorten version, since the result of the screen above origins from that source. I will add a caption inside the sample code to indicate the RED and purple view.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It wans't actually about anything special. It was about the nine-patch chat bubble which caused the issue.